# Passing in a raster image to a C extension from PostgreSQL

Tags: c, postgresql, postgis, raster, gdal

I'm writing a function in a C/C++ extension that does some image processing of a PostGIS raster that I wish to call from a PostgreSQL database. I would like to pass this in from the postgres function as an argument and read it in the C extension. However, I don't know how to do this. postgres.h had no method to read in the argument from the 'PG_FUNCTION_ARGS'. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: I think I can just convert it to bytea, and reconstruct it in C. Not ideal, but I can pass it as an argument this way.

Comment: Take a look at the [PostGIS source](https://github.com/postgis/postgis) and see how they do it

Comment: Oh that is a really good idea. Thanks!